VSCode Flutter - Turn off Intrusive "Help"
Working on my first flutter app, but the obscenely intrusive "help" system gets right in my way all the time. A rather tame example is pasted below.
I need this out of my way.
Any help?


this is either hover or parameter hints. are you hovering your mouse over the thing?

Not on hover, definitely parameter hints that have gone a fair bit overboard.
Thing is, I get them almost every keystroke.
I've tried going through all of the settings (both through "settings" and settings.json) , but can't find anything that seems to address this.
I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but can't see what.
